# React redux reducer getting data from state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Trying to mess around with react and redux to fetch a list of files from an API.

When looking in the react dev tools I can see my data there but it is not being rendered.

**actions.js**

```
export const requestFiles  = ({
    type: REQUEST_FILES,
});

export const receiveFiles = (json) => ({
    type: RECEIVE_FILES,
    files: json,
    receivedAt: Date.now()
});


export const fetchFiles = (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(requestFiles);
    return fetch('/api/files')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => dispatch(receiveFiles(json)))
};
```

The action gets data from JSON

[image]

**reducer.js**

```
const files = (state = {
    isFetching: false,
    items: []
}, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case REQUEST_FILES:
            return {
                ...state,
                isFetching: true,
            };
        case RECEIVE_FILES:
            return {
                ...state,
                isFetching: false,
                items: action.files,
                lastUpdated: action.receivedAt
            };
        default:
            return state
    }
};

const filesUploaded = (state = { }, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case RECEIVE_FILES:
        case REQUEST_FILES:
            return {
                ...state,
                items: files(state[action], action)
            };
        default:
            return state
    }
};

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    filesUploaded
});

export default rootReducer
```

**App.js**

```
class App extends Component {
    static propTypes = {
        files: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
        isFetching: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
        dispatch: PropTypes.func.isRequired
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        const {dispatch} = this.props;
        dispatch(fetchFiles);
    }

    handleChange = nextSubreddit => {
    };

    render() {
        const {files, isFetching} = this.props;
        const isEmpty = files.length === 0;
        console.log(`Files is empty ${isEmpty}`);
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Uploadr</h1>
                {isEmpty
                    ? (isFetching ? <h2>Loading...</h2> : <h2>No files.</h2>)
                    : <div style={{opacity: isFetching ? 0.5 : 1}}>
                        <Files files={files}/>
                    </div>
                }
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    const {uploadedFiles} = state;
    const {isFetching, items: files} = uploadedFiles
        || {isFetching: true, items: []};

    console.log(files);

    return {
        files,
        isFetching,
    }
};
```

[image]

The data being received in the action but I am not sure if it is getting stored or if the problem is accessing it from the redux store.

The files property is still zero on the App component as shown in the screenshot above.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you look in the `next state` does that have the information you requested?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete your `filesUploaded` reducer.  You don't need it.  Instead, just use the `files` reducer:

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    files,
});
```

Please note, the slice of state you are interested in will be called `files`.  Change your `mapStateToProps` function to this:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    const {isFetching, items: files} = state.files

    console.log(files);

    return {
        files,
        isFetching,
    }
};
```

You can see here, we grab the `files` slice of state and pass that into your component.

Comment: You da real MVP

Comment: Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 1):

Your `filesUploaded` reducer does not make any sense. I'm not sure what `filesUploaded` is even supposed to be doing. Your `files` reducer looks like a normal reducer. It seems like you could just delete `filesUploaded` and everything would be fine.

In particular, `filesUploaded` is calling `files(state[action], action)`. `action` is an object. What is `state[SOME_OBJECT]` supposed to be? Because it's being parsed as `state['[object Object]']` which is surely undefined and never would become defined.

Your `files` reducer also has an `items` parameter that is just never used. A reducer should only have two parameters: state and action. Drop the items parameter.

Your `mapStateToProps` is looking for `state.uploadedFiles`, but your reducer is called `filesUploaded`. It should be `state.filesUploaded` (or if you replace it with the `files` reducer, just `state.files`).

`mapStateToProps` will not need `|| {isFetching: true, items: []}` since you have an initial state on your `files` reducer.

Comment: Thanks, I was using this as an example - https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/tree/master/examples/async/src/reducers